# Get ticks on x-axis with scalesBand centered below columns with d3 v6

Tags: d3.js, axis-labels

#### Edit: Problem solved

The bitter insight: I have done the translate wrong: the axis is wrongly moved to the right. **Solution**
`.attr('transform',` translate(0,${input.height - margins.current.bottom})`)`

#### Original Post

I do not understand how to get the positions of the ticks of my x-axis right. The ticks should be centered right below the columns.

With *d3* I am creating a [band scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/v4.0.0/README.md#scaleBand) for the right width of the columns and I would like to reuse it for the x-axis.

#### Code

```
// data
data [
  {
    "year": "2021",
    "value": 7.81335178927304
  },
  {
    "year": "2022",
    "value": 7.103485903424945
  },
  {
    "year": "2023",
    "value": 6.393620017576849
  }
  // [...]
]

// original band scale
const xScale = scaleBand()
    .domain(yearsData.map((d) :string => d.year))
    .rangeRound([0, (input.width - margins.current.left - margins.current.right)])
    .padding(0.1);

// creating the x-axis
const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale.copy().padding(0.5).align(0));
const xAxisGroup = chartGroup.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x-axis')
    .call(xAxis)
    // move the whole axis down, variables do not matter here
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margins.current.left},${input.height - margins.current.bottom})`)
```

#### Result

[image: Weird position of ticks:]

#### Do I need to use [timeScale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/v4.0.0/README.md#scaleTime) here?

Different ways of setting paddings on the copied band scale produces different results, but no centered ticks. Also I am wondering about the very first tick on the left, why is it there? Trying [point scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173160/data-points-and-ticks-in-the-scaleband-axis-are-not-aligned) did not work, too.